# How to replace duplicate elements in Array List?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I'm trying to replace duplicate elements in Array List with new unique ids. so that order of elements is not lost but duplicate values alone get changed to new ones.

```
ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<> Arrays.asList("111111111","446463636","111111111","343634633","111111111"));
for(int i=0; i< aa.size();i++) {
    if(aa.get(i)==null){
        String uuids = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        aa.add(uuids);
        aa.remove(aa.get(i));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to `set` the element at the same index as the duplicate entry. If you `add` the element to the list you'll be placing the element at the back. Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (Collections.frequency(list, list.get(i)) > 1) {
        String uuids = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
        list.set(i, uuids);
    }
}
```